How to access a GKE internal Knative service from a VM in the same VPC
I have a GKE autopilot private cluster (running in a fleet) with the CloudRun (i.e. Knative) feature enabled.
I followed https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/enterprise/knative-serving/docs/setup#setting_up_a_private_internal_network:

Created an internal passthrough load-balancer, following https://cloud.google.com/service-mesh/docs/operate-and-maintain/gateways#managed-istiod using the deployment yamls from https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/anthos-service-mesh-packages/tree/main/samples/gateways/istio-ingressgateway
Opened port 15017 as per https://cloud.google.com/service-mesh/docs/operate-and-maintain/private-cluster-open-port (though my autopilot private cluster does not have a master-ipv4-cidr, so I set source ranges for my subnet, the Cluster Pod IPv4 range, and the IPv4 service range).
Created a sample "helloworld" Knative service with external ingress allowed.
Created a sample "helloworld-internal" Knative service with external ingress blocked (using networking.knative.dev/visibility: cluster-local).
Created proxy-only subnet and firewall rule as per https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/internal-load-balance-ingress#deploy-ingress
Created a Gateway as per https://cloud.google.com/service-mesh/docs/operate-and-maintain/gateways#gateway_selectors

Going back to https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/enterprise/knative-serving/docs/setup#setting_up_a_private_internal_network, I created a Compute Engine virtual machine (VM) in the same zone as the GKE cluster. From this VM I can curl to the "helloworld" service using its external DNS name - curl -H Host:<external_url> http:<ilb-ip> - but I can not curl to the "helloworld-internal" service.
With my deployment steps coming from multiple Google docs sources I'm sure I'm missing something, but no idea what.
My end goal is to use Cloud Run (managed) with Direct VPC access to call my internal GKE Knative services.

This is a limitation of native clusters, GKE Services can only be accessible within the cluster and not accessible outside the cluster such as VM instances. The recommended approach is to use an Internal passthrough Load Balancer that is available within the same VPC network and region.

I followed many steps, listed in my question, to create an ILB, but something is missing or wrong. Please see the steps I followed and the result of my testing.
